# How to add a contextual ligature to OpenType font, a free tool

Tags: font-design, font-forge, opentype, ligatures

I use Fontforge, where plain 'liga' ligatures work, but now I would like to use a contextual ligature. Fontforge does not help here, as its support for both contextual chaining and for Apple state machines segfaults. Also, that kind of substitutions seems too bloated to me when it goes to simple contextual features. See the ~30 GUI dialogs in https://fontforge.org/editexample6-5.html#OpenType which explain a simple ligature or this guide https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/121528/146881.

So I can buy an expensive font editor, but I would not want to do it just in order to add another ligature, and Fontforge, apart from the problem in question, works well enough.

Instead, I would like to use one of the OTF features as described here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/78329 or here https://ilovetypography.com/OpenType/opentype-features.html. And here is the question: any free utility for Linux, which can add declarations to an OTF file like:

```
feature clig {
  sub space a' b' by AB;
} clig;
```

Preferably scriptable, so that I can have a script to transform Fontforge's OTF output. It would be most straightforward to do it in Fontforge itself, but I am not sure if it is possible.

I am a programmer, transforming XML files produced by for example https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools would not possibly be a problem, but I do not know where to start.

Comment: You can script fontforge